# How to auto-intercept many invocation of a Java method?

Tags: java, aop, code-injection

we are trying to collect metrics on how our code uses an external API. Suppose I want to intercept our call to the API A.f(). From [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576918/how-do-i-intercept-a-method-invocation-with-standard-java-features-no-aspectj-e) I see we can intercept it by proxy an instance. By can we do this for all such instances? We probably call this function at least hundreds of times, we can't proxy all such instances.

Thanks!

Comment: is this what AspectJ does?

Comment: nvm, I found that I can use Guice bindIntercepter and custom Matcher to do this.

Comment: Yes, it can be done with AspectJ. But this is not the right question format for StackOverflow. Please either delete your question or ask a concrete question with sample code.